# Python - 'No module named'

Tags: python, import

Ok, so I'm very new to programming and I'm just getting through Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard way.

In the book he simply tells me to type 'import ex25', where ex25 is a file I've saved. It is saved as 'ex25.py'

But I keep getting an error telling me that 'No module named ex25', and I have no idea why.

I have never used the Python shell before so I'm not sure whether or not I was supposed to do something beforehand regarding directories and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the file in your working directory?

Comment: @CactusWoman Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what that is. This is the first time I've used Python shell, I have been using Windows PowerShell prior to this.

Comment: Ensure both files are in the same directory also cd to that directory before executing the script.

Answer (score 1):

Place the file in the same directory as the file you are calling the module into, the problem your are having is with the visibility of the file